# Automatic space after comma in Code cell style

Tags: front-end, options, cells, stylesheet

`"Input"` cell style automatically inserts a space after each comma, with natural exceptions such as when quotation marks are open.

`"Code"` cell style does not.

After looking through all the style definitions and using the options inspector, I cannot see how this behaviour is controlled.

I would like `"Code"` cells to behave like `"Input"` cells with respect to comma handling; how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The setting you are looking for is `AutoSpacing -> True`.

And you need to set it on a stylesheet level for `"Code"` cells or on a `Cell` level in a notebook (which does not make sense for .m files).